# Variadic template doesn't work under g++, but works under MSVC++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25832646/3821804). Why this code doesn't compiles under g++ while it compiles under VC++?
How can I make the code portable?

My code:

```
template<typename T>
inline T sum(T t){
    return t;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
inline auto sum(T t, Ts... ts)->decltype(t+sum(ts...)){
    return t+sum(ts...);
}

#include<iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout<<sum(2.5, 2)<<'\n'            //works
             <<sum(2, 2.5)<<'\n';           //works
    std::cout<<sum(1u, 2.5, 3.f, '0')<<'\n';//doesn't work, don't know why
}
```

[See it in online compiler under g++](http://rextester.com/XXZYU26184)
[See it in online compiler under MSVC++](http://rextester.com/SHIG74390)

Comment: The variadic version of `sum` isn't in scope until its declarator is complete, so you can't use it in the trailing return type (which is part of the declarator).

Comment: @T.C. What you suggest me to do to make the code correct?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus In C++14, simply use return type deduction. In C++11, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744400/trailing-return-type-using-decltype-with-a-variadic-template-function.